# How to open an internal frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frame, mdi

i open a new internalframe in this main frame, i have 2 class,

```
    DisplayInternalFrame aDisplay = new DisplayInternalFrame(name, surname);
    desktop.add(aDisplay);
    aDisplay.setMaximum(true);
    aDisplay.show()
```

i have a desktop pane and its name desktop, this is my main frame, the internal frame is loading when the application runs,

now my 2nd class is internalframe, it has a table, i want to open new internal frame when people push a table item, my table name is errorTable

```
 private void errorTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

 errorInternalFrame acceptFrame = new errorInternalFrame();

 desktop.add(acceptFrame);
```

the desktop is on the class 1 so i cant reach desktop cuz now i am on the internalframe event,

basically when people push an item on the table on the internalframe, open a new internal frame, or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> "the desktop is on the class 1 so i cant reach desktop cuz now i am on the internalframe event, "

What you can do is create an `interface` with a method to `addToDesktop`

```
public interface AddableDesktop {
    public void addToDesktop();
}
```

Then in your class with the desktop, implement it

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements AddableDesktop {
    private JDesktopPane desktop;

    @Override
    public void addToDesktop() {
        errorInternalFrame acceptFrame = new errorInternalFrame();
        desktop.add(acceptFrame); 
        acceptFrame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

You'll also need to pass the `Main` instance (which is an instance of `AddableDesktop`) to the `DisplayInternalFrame`. Then you can call the `addToDesktop` method.

```
public class DisplayInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    private AddableDesktop addableDesktop;

    public DisplayInternalFrame(String name, String surname, AddableDesktop ad) {
        this.addableDesktop = ad;
    }

    ...
    private void errorTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        addableDesktop.addToDesktop();
    }
}
```

When you create the `DisplayInternalFrame` in your `Main` class, you'll pass the `Main` instance to the contructor

```
DisplayInternalFrame aDisplay = 
                     new DisplayInternalFrame(name, surname, Main.this);
```

This may not be the exact set up you're looking for, but it shows how you provide functionality from one class to the another.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will try to use an interface.